# Trying to write functions in JSON, get "Unexpected token" within function call

Tags: javascript, json

I've learned that you can write functions within JSON files, but I keep running into `unexpected token` errors. Here's the JSON I'm using below:

```
[

    {
        "thumb": "./templates/scripts/thumbs/01.jpg",
        "get": function() {
            console.log('mthood');
        },
        "title": "Mt. Hood Sunset",
        "desc": "A relaxing view of Mt. Hood, Oregon."
    },
    {
        "thumb": "./templates/scripts/thumbs/02.jpg",
        "get": function() {
            console.log('misty');
        },
        "title": "Misty Rainforest",
        "desc": "Leafy and wet at the same time. "
    },
    {
        "thumb": "./templates/scripts/thumbs/03.jpg",
        "get": function() {
            console.log('clouds');
        },
        "title": "Clouds",
        "desc": "Blue skies and white clouds."
    }

]
```

JSONLint gives me a more detailed error, but I'm not sure I can follow what's going on here:

```
Error: Parse error on line 5:
...s/01.jpg",       "get": function() {         cons
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is not valid JSON, you cant embed function in JSON

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're trying to put a function in a JSON object?

Comment: You've learned 2 things - 1) That you can put functions in a json file and 2) It's no longer valid json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONLint validates JSON as a whole, not JSON as defined by JavaScript. JavaScript Object, while they look like JSON, aren't JSON. JSON doesn't allow for functions, because JSON is a data-interchange format, like XML. Your code works, you can open up your developer console in Chrome and test it, but it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for correctly identifying my issue. I appear to have been mislead into thinking that I could write functions in JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You can't add functions to a JSON, just static data, like arrays, strings, numbers or booleans.

Answer (score 2):

> "I've learned that you can use functions within JSON files".

It's not standardized, where did you read that? JSON just accepts [7 primitive types:](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor8)

- array
- boolean
- integer
- number
- null
- object
- string

Comment: I appear to have mixed up JSON with JavaScript Objects, which are similar, but not identical. This helps, thanks!

Comment: @Thassa Ok :) Indeed you can use functions as object properties in Javascript, but Javascript objects are not JSON, even if their format seems similar